# ODBC SQL server not found in R Studio Server

Tags: odbc, rstudio-server, azure-sql-server, r-dbi

I'm trying to connect an Azure SQL instance to my R Studio Server that is served on Ubuntu.

```
library(DBI)

library(odbc)

con_string <- paste(c('DRIVER', "PORT", "SERVER", "DATABASE", "UID", "PWD"),
                    c('{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}', 1433,
                      "mydatabase.database.secure.windows.net", "DB1",
                      "me", "foo"),
                    sep = "=", collapse = ";")


con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = con_string)
```

The error I get:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 01000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found
```

I've tried all of the other drivers:

```
{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}
{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}
```

I can't connect. I've used `pyodbc` in other environments and been able to connect with the same string.

I confirm that the ODBC libraries are installed:

```
ubuntu@ip-1-2-3-4:~$ sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev --install-suggests
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
unixodbc is already the newest version (2.3.1-4.1).
unixodbc-dev is already the newest version (2.3.1-4.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1048 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1049 linux-headers-4.4.0-1048-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1049-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1048-aws
  linux-image-4.4.0-1049-aws
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 107 not upgraded
```

.It appears that the drivers are not available from within my R environment or I'm calling it the wrong thing. [This is the R Server docs that I'm reading](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/drivers/)

Comment: Accepted solution below. In my case it was that the path variable was set to the wrong location and the R library could not find the SQL Server Driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem doesn't comes from the `unix-odbc` lib. 
Indeed as you can see in this:

```
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found
```

**2 Solutions are to try:**

- The problem is the driver is not found. It can be due because your driver is not correctly installed in your computer. Verify you followed the installation step.
- It can also be caused by a missing `-Wl,-rpath,<Link to your gcc driver library>` option in the compilation of your C++ application. But as the **R Language** is written in C this should not influence you.

Comment: Can you recommend an approach for 'verify you followed the installation'? Is there a good way to quickly verify that the driver is installed and working properly?

Comment: @billmanH What you can try is to create a table in your database and the try a query like `select * from table;` using your ODBC Driver with the following command: `echo "select * from table;" | isql -v ODBC "Driver 17 for SQL Server"`

Comment: @billmanH If your client is on linux too, what is inside your `/etc/odbc.ini` and `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file to describe your driver. (Don't forget to remove username and password from it before sending informations). To reproduce your bug, I needed to precise in the `/etc/odbcinst.ini file` a wrong path to my dynamic library: `01000:1:0:[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/home/.../libv2odbc.so' : file not found`.